# Segmentation fault in a program that reverses a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, segmentation-fault, dynamic-allocation

I was doing a test and the online test engine showing segmentation error, which is confusing because with no further details, and I checked the pointer no NULL and they work pretty fine, but don't how **array** here works. Because when debugging, everything is fine, until I try to cout/print out the array. it's reporting a is crushed here and break. I can do nothing here if it break, and I hit break or continue. if I continue, it runs just fine. so I was really confused.

My computer is windows 7, I run code in visual studio 2010 c++. 
Debugging is not that clear to solve the problem, and I am learning c++ not very efficient.
Solve with **Array** need dynamic allocation.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void reverseArray(int size, int num[]) {
    if(size>1) {
        int *p = &num[size-1];
        int *f = num;
        for(int i = 0;i < size/2; i++){
            swap(*p, *f);
            p--;
            f++;
        } 
    }
}

int main() {
    int len;
    int a[len];/This is the bug, can't use uninitialized var assign array/
    cin >> len;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    reverseArray(len, a);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has something to with dynamic allocation, when I work in java, I create a new array. 
I have to

```
int[] newArray = {2,4,1,2,3};
```

or

```
int[] newArray = new int[] {2,4,1,2,3};
```

Finally, this problem is solved, which makes me very happy.
Reading and learning is very important, coding is also important. 
Thanks all,

And using **vector** instead of using array. 
It would be easier.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;
    int len;
    vector<int> myvector;
    cin >> len;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cin >> a;
        myvector.push_back(a);
    }
    reverse(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << myvector[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using **Array** again(*I doubt the following code*):

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void reverseArray(int size, int nums[]){
    if(size > 1){
        int *p = &nums[size-1];
        int *q = nums;
        for(int i = 0; i< size/2; i++){
            swap(*p, *q);
            p--;
            q++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int len;
    cin >> len;
    int *a = new int[len];//a point to the first ele.

    for(int i = 0; i< len; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    reverseArray(len, a);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    delete [] a;
    return 0;

}
```

It worked perfect on my laptop, which is confusing because a is pointer, but I use it like an array. It shouldn't be working......

Final Array version: 
http://ideone.com/ZMsD35
Done perfectly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int len;
    cin >> len;
    int *a = new int[len];
    for(int i = 0; i< len; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    reverse(a, a+len);
    for(int i = 0; i< len; i++){
        cout << a[i];
    }
    delete [] a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129268/discussion-on-question-by-r-mia-segmentation-fault-in-a-program-that-reverses-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for a segfault is the input. When the testing software passes `len` of size sufficient to overflow the automatic storage area, your program crashes on this line:

```
int a[len];
```

The exact value of `len` is system-dependent, but an input of 1,000,000 should do it on most common systems.

The fix is really straightforward - replace the declaration with

```
int a* = new int[len];
```

This will place the data in dynamic memory, rather than the automatic memory. It will also make your program standard-compliant, because variable-length arrays in C++ are an extension to standards.

Don't forget to delete `a` once you are done to avoid memory leak:

```
delete[] a;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot! It's now working, may I know the difference between the key two lines? Do I need to delete every pointer?

Comment: @R.mia This changes the placement of your data from automatic memory (stack) to dynamic memory (heap).

Comment: May I know what is the related document or link I can refer to /

Comment: @R.mia This should be covered in your C++ textbook. Look up "dynamic allocation" and "operator new". Pay attention to the difference between operator `delete` and operator `delete[]` with square brackets.

Comment: but we need to delete every dynamic allocation pointer? and new int[ ] is pretty much the same as java, could you tell me some relationship between java and c++ , which one would be more easier and less trouble. Since c++ is always giving me trouble.....

Comment: @R.mia Yes, you need to delete everything that you allocate with `new`. Java's syntax borrowed a few things from C++. Other than that, the two languages are very different.

Comment: I looked up the new operator, when I assign *p point to the first type of the array, and then operate p[i] like p is an array. and it works......I copied the code above.